# Any way to label variables in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have the nexy code in Python

```
Id=np.arange(1,16)

l=np.arange(1,101).tolist()

Ing=random.choices(l,k=15)

base2= pd.DataFrame({'Id':Id,'Ingreso':Ing,})

base2=base2.set_index('Id')

base2['Grupo'] = pd.cut(base2['Ingreso'], bins=[0,30,50,70,100],labels=[1,2,3,4], include_lowest=True)

grouped = base2.groupby(['Ingreso', 'Grupo'], as_index=False)

s=np.arange(0,2).tolist()

base2['Sexo']= random.choices(s,k=15)
```

With this dataframe I want to do a Crosstable

```
pd.crosstab(base2.Grupo,base2.Sexo)
```

And this is my output

```
Sexo   0  1
Grupo      
1      1  2
2      2  2
3      0  3
4      3  2
```

But I want something Like this

```
Sexo Men Women 
Grupo      
1      1  2
2      2  2
3      0  3
4      3  2
```

It is posible in Python ?

Comment: try pd.crosstab(base2.Grupo,base2.Sexo).set_axis(['Men','Women'],axis='columns')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) before.

```
pd.crosstab(base2.Grupo, base2.Sexo.map({0 : 'Men', 1 : 'Women'}))
```

or [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) after.

```
pd.crosstab(base2.Grupo, base2.Sexo).rename(columns={0 : 'Men', 1 : 'Women'})
```

**Output**

```
Sexo Men Women 
Grupo      
1      1  2
2      2  2
3      0  3
4      3  2
```